# How to pass non default argument with default arguments in python django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-formwizard

Here is my code

```
class FarticlesWizard(FormWizard):

    def done(self,request,form_list):

        if request.method=='POST':
            form1=F1articles(request.POST)  
            form2=F2articles(request.POST)
            form_dict={}
            for x in form_list:
                form_dict=dict(form_dict.items()+x.cleaned_data.items())
                insert_db=Marticles(heading = form_dict['heading'],
                                    content = form_dict['content'],
                                    created_by=request.session['user_name'],    
                                    country=form_dict['country'],
                                    work=form_dict['work'])
                insert_db.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/display/')
```

but i now i need to pass def `done(self,request,id=None, form_list):` where id is non default argument ...iam getting an error message `non-default argument follows default argument (views.py, line 130)` is there a way to do it?

Comment: Not related to question but can you please use pep8 while formatting your code - put spaces before and after '=' in places where you assign variable names - this will improve code readablitity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  As the error message suggests, any arguments with default values must come after all arguments without default values.

Why do you feel you need to add the new argument in the middle like that?  Why not just do `def done(self, request, form_list, id=None)`?  Adding a new argument in the middle will break all existing code that calls the function with positional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Default arguments have to all go after non default arguments, or positional argument passing is messed up. If you have `def done(self,request,id=None,form_list):` and you call `done(r,fl)` somewhere, python doesn't know if fl goes in id or form_list. You'll always have to specify id to get to specifying form_list. That's why default arguments all go at the end, like `def done(self,request,form_list,id=None)`